# Mongoose find use result in the main code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var result = false;

thecollecton.findOne({name: "hey"}, function(err,obj) { 
    if(err) console.log(err);
    if(obj) result=true;
});

 console.log(result);
 // do other things with result
```

And... it doesn't work (and I know why). 
How can I make it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `findOne()` call is asynchronous. When you call `console.log()`, the execution of `findOne()` is not finished yet. You need to call `console.log()` inside the asynchronous function:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var result = false;

thecollecton.findOne({name: "hey"}, function(err,obj) { 
    if(err) console.log(err);
    if(obj) result=true;
    console.log(result);
});
```

**Edit:** Replying to the comment. If this query is in a function and you want to use the result of the query in the caller, then you need to pass a callback to the function. For this, you need to modify the function to accept a callback, for example:

```
function exists(name, callback) {
  thecollecton.findOne({name: name}, function(err,obj) {
    var result = (err || !obj) ? false : true;
    callback(result);
  });
}
```

And then call this function with a callback:

```
exists('hey', function(result) {
  if (result) {
    // Do something.
  }
});
```

Comment: He knows why... Just add that it isn't possible

Comment: yeah I know it but I want to use the result after in the main code, is there a workaround to do it ?

Comment: @user3491456 I see. The `findOne()` call is asynchronous, so it's not possible to achieve what you want. You need to run the rest of the code inside the callback. You can also look into using a promise, it might help to structure your code a bit better: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#promise_Promise-addBack

Comment: in fact, i'm making the db query in a function. I want the function to return true or false, depending on query's result...

Comment: @user3491456 Edited my answer to show you a way how to use result value in the caller.